# Creando archivos con Touch

Tags: bash, shell

Tengo que crear, de cada archivo que me pasan por parámetro, un fichero con cada línea de la forma *nombreDelArchivo*.*numeroDeLaLínea*. El código que pensé es el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $@
do
    i=0
    if [[ -s $file ]]
    then
        echo $file | while read line
        do
            (( i++ ))
            echo $line >> /var/log/FicherosDeTexto/$file.$i
        done
    else
        touch /var/log/FicherosDeTexto/$file.$i
    fi
done
```

El caso es que al crear cada uno de los ficheros me dan los siguientes errores:

```
touch: no se puede efectuar `touch' sobre «/var/log/FicherosDeTexto/FicherosAyuda/Vacio.0»: No existe el fichero o el directorio

./act1.sh: línea 11: /var/log/FicherosDeTexto/FicherosAyuda/Archivo3lineas.1: No existe el fichero o el directorio
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese error lo produce la inexistencia de parte de la ruta; si el archivo a crear es

```
/home/trauma/prueba/ruta2/hola.txt
```

y el directorio `/home/trauma/prueba/ruta2` no existe, provoca ese error.

Asegurate de que los nombres de archivo no incluyan el caracter '/', y prueba a poner `mkdir -p RUTAS/A/CREAR` antes de crear los archivos.

Comment: De hecho, el problema era que el `$file` cogía los directorios. Lo solucioné cambiando el `$file.$i`por `$(basename $file).$i`. Muchas gracias!